# No Index Error in Conditional within List Comprehension

Tags: python, list, indexing, list-comprehension

When I run the code:

```
mylist = []
mylist[1]
```

I get IndexError: list index out of range. This makes sense to me. But when I run the following code:

```
mylist = []
newlist = [x for x in mylist if mylist[1] == 'mystring']
print(newlist)
```

I don't get an index error, it just prints an empty list. This is what I want the code to do, but I don't understand why it doesn't give me and IndexError. From what I can tell, this only occurs when the the list is empty, otherwise you could get an index error if you indexed the list out of range. For example:

```
mylist = ['string']
newlist = [x for x in mylist if mylist[1] == 'mystring']
```

returns the IndexError I would expect it to return.

If anyone could help explain why if you have a conditional statement specifying an index of an empty list in a list comprehension, you don't get an index error, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Just a note: with `mylist[1]` you're trying to acces the SECOND element of the list, not to the first one. The first element in list is `list[0]`, the second element is `list[1]` and so on.

Comment: Uhuh the index level was arbitrary for the sake of the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `[x for x in mylist if mylist[1] == 'mystring']`, the `if mylist[1] == 'mystring'` clause is executed for each iteration - but since `mylist` is empty, there is exactly zero iteration, so it's not executed at all.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with conditionals and comprehensions. It's simply the fact that iterating over an empty sequence or collection produces no iterations. Notice how the following code block doesn't produce an error in the `for` loop, even though `x` is not defined:

```
>>> a = 0
>>> for i in []:
...     x = x + 2
...
>>> a
0
>>> x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `mylist` is already empty, `for x in mylist` will never iterate so `if` check will never be executed. Same thing applies for normal `for` loops as well:

```
>>> mylist = []
>>> for x in mylist:
...     print "second item", mylist[1]

# will print nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `if mylist[1] == 'mystring'` is evaluated for each value in `mylist`.

As `mylist` is empty, the expression is never evaluated.